# How quickly do crew suffocate without oxygen?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I'm in a situation where I'd like to teleport my men onto a drone, bust up their shields, then teleport back. As you may know, however, drones have no oxygen. I'm worried about how much damage my crew will take before the teleport cooldown depletes.

How many hitpoints do crewmen lose per second while in rooms with zero life support?

Comment: It varies by species, but I lost an Engie and a Human while my first-level teleporter recharged.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I applied science with the following result:

It takes 15 seconds for a 100 HP crewmember entering a low oxygen room or a room running out of oxygen to die. This means they lose health at a rate of 6.67 HP/s. This rate appears to be constant across all races, meaning

- Rockmen get killed after 22.5 seconds
- Humans, Mantis, Engi, Slugs get killed after 15 seconds
- Zoltans after 10.5 seconds.

*4 Humans, 2 Engi, a Rockman and a Mantis were killed performing this experiment.*

Comment: The crystal races have a reduced suffocation rate. Do you think you could run the same test on them and include the results in the answer?

Comment: So... how long does a fully upgraded crew transport take to recharge?

Comment: If the in-game numbers are correct, Crystal beings should last 37.5 seconds.  The teleporter recharges in 20, 15 or 10 seconds (at 1, 2 or 3 power, respectively).  Since a level 2 teleporter is sufficient for most races, I suppose transport time cuts about a second off the time your crew spends suffocating.

Answer (score 5):

Asphyxiation does as much damage as a level 1 med-bay heals. More importantly, a level 1 teleporter will not recharge before most crew members will die (not sure about rockmen or crystalmen). A level 2 teleporter will recharge before a 100 hp crew member dies (not sure about a zoltan).

---

Crystal crew will have 60 health left when the level 1 teleporter is back online.

Comment: This does not answer the question. What is the rate?

Comment: Between 5 and 6.7 health per second. Why do you need an exact rate?

Answer (score 2):

Crystal crew will still have 60 health left when the level 1 teleporter is back online when entering an oxygen depleted room.